# C - using fgetc to store value in enum 'class'

Tags: c, struct, enums, fgetc

I am writing a program that accepts a file with database entries in it.  The entries are all in the same format, with the data in the same order.  The first number in the file is the number of entries.  Then the data looks like this:
LastName FirstName StudentID age year GPA expectedGraduationDate

Ex:
Doe John 12345678 23 freshman 4.0 2013

My issue is with the year value.  We are supposed to declare it as type 'class', which is supposed to be `enum class{freshman, sophomore, junior, senior, grad};`

I have a header file with the following declaration:

```
typedef enum {firstYear, sophomore, junior, senior, grad} class;
```

Then my main file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "class.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

typedef struct{
        int DBrecordID;         //ID for each entry, range 0-319
        char *last;             //student last name
        char *first;            //student first name
        char studentID[8];      //student ID
        int age;                //student age
        class year;             //year in school
        float gpa;              //GPA
        int expGradYear;        //expected graduation year
}DBrecord;
int numEntries;
DBrecord **record;
char buffer[80];
FILE *fpt;
int c, i;
int j = 0;

//check for invalid file arguments
if(argc != 2){
        printf("Number of arguments is invalid\n");
        exit(1);
}

//error if unable to open file
if((fpt = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error: Couldn't open file.\n");
        exit(1);
}

//set file pointer to read passed file
fpt = fopen(argv[1], "r");

//scan first int in file and assign to numEntries
//fscanf(fpt, "%d", &numEntries);

//allocate memory for structures, each is 36 bytes
*record = malloc (sizeof (DBrecord) * numEntries);

//loop through each DB entry
do{
        for(i=0; i<numEntries; i++){
                numEntries = record[i]->DBrecordID;
                do{
                        c=fgetc(fpt);
                        buffer[j++] = c;
                }while(c != ' ');
                        strcpy(record[i]->last, buffer);
                        j=0;
                do{
                        c=fgetc(fpt);
                        buffer[j++] = c;
                }while(c != ' ');
                        strcpy(record[i]->first, buffer);
                        j=0;
                do{
                        c=fgetc(fpt);   
                        buffer[j++] = c;
                }while(c != ' ');
                        strcpy(record[i]->studentID, buffer);
                        j=0;
                do{
                        c=fgetc(fpt);
                        memcpy(c, buffer[j++], 1);
               }while(c != ' ');
                        memcpy(buffer, record[i]->year, 4);
                        j=0;
                do{
                        c=fgetc(fpt);
                        buffer[j++] = c;
                }while(c != ' ');
                        memcpy(buffer, record[i]->gpa, 4);
                        j=0;
                do{  
                        c=fgetc(fpt);
                        buffer[j++] = c;
                }while(c != ' ' || c != '\n');
                        memcpy(buffer, record[i]->expGradYear, 4);
                        j=0;
         }
}while(c != EOF);

return 0;
}
```

*Updated errors

main.c:75: warning: passing arg 1 of `memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast

main.c:75: warning: passing arg 2 of `memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast

main.c:77: incompatible type for argument 2 of `memcpy'

main.c:83: incompatible type for argument 2 of `memcpy'

main.c:89: warning: passing arg 2 of `memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast

main.c:94: parse error before "DBrecord"

So I'm assuming I can't do what I'm trying to do with memcpy, or I'm just doing it wrong.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There quite a few errors in the program but for a start

1) `record` should be of type `DBrecord*` not `DBrecord**`

2) `strcpy` takes destination as the first argument so  this wouldn't work
 `strcpy(buffer, record[i]->last);`

3) you also need to allocate memory for `record[i]->last`

4)  `strcpy` is used to copy strings so if you wan't to store  to float or int  i.e. gpa etc you need to use `memcpy` also the value from buffer should be converted using `strol` `strod`

also would recommend to get hold of this book [K&R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) it would be really helpful overtime

Comment: I'm pretty sure I declared `record` properly.  I need a double pointer to point to both part of the structure, `DBrecord` and `DBrecord.last` or `DBrecord.first` etc.  Thanks for the `strcpy` tip, I see that I got the arguments backwards.  As far as memory allocation, I used `*record = malloc (sizeof (DBrecord) * numEntries);`  Why would I need to allocate more memory?  And finally, I guess I need help understanding `memcpy`.  Why does the buffer need to be converted if `memcpy` doesn't care what type is passed?  Thanks for the help!  I know I must seem pretty clueless.

Comment: @manalishi lets take DBrecord first , when you use `DBrecord ** record`, and `*record = malloc`. record is not intialized so `*record` would seg fault , i think what you intend is array of DBrecord which is `DBrecord*` since array decays to pointer . Secondly when allocate sizeof(DbRecord)  for fields like last_name what you have allocated is size for the pointer  but the pointer `last_name` now needs to be intialized to a valid address so you need to allocate. I would recommend first try get the program to compile then one by one  iron out logic issues using debugger

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not following you.  Would you look at [my other post about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076261/c-build-dynamically-allocated-array-of-pointers-to-structures-filled-with-inpu) and let me know if you still feel like it's wrong?  The comments seemed to agree.

Comment: @manalishi  i'm not sure why you want a array of pointers to DbRecord here is an example to show why what you  have would not work: http://codepad.org/726Vt5RE. I you have array of pointers you need to allocate space for the array of pointers then for individual pointers i believe that post is wrong. when you say *rec = malloc(<somthing>) it assumes rec is pointing to a valid address `DBrecord **rec;` you have not intialized rec , if you intialize it to null  and do `*rec` you will see a segfault

Comment: I had to think about it all day, but I finally am coming around and I think I understand the segfault.  Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you try to `strcpy` (**String** Copy) from an `int`, like `expGradYear`?

`strcpy` is for STRINGS.   If you want to append an int to a buffer, use `memcpy` (**MEMory** Copy)